# flash (as3) / php communication not as easy as in as2

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a question... how to get a Var from php into an running flash application scripted in as3?
There was a function called _root in as2 but it seems not to work in as3?!?

Is there a easy way (without a socket) to receive php vars in as3?

Thx

Comment: hi marius, did u find the answer yet or not.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're talking about getting **FlashVars** from the embedded SWF, in AS2 they were attached to `_root`. Now they are attached to the `LoaderInfo.parameters` property for a particular loaded SWF object.

So to get the one from `root` you could do

```
var flashVars:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
```

And grab your loaded vars like this...

```
flashVars.myVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`root.loaderInfo.parameters`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#parameters) contains all flash vars.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("someurl");

        url.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendComplete);
        urlLoader.load(saveAudio);

        function sendComplete(evt:Event):void
        {

            var id = evt.target.data.id;
        }
```

in someurl you need to write down like this (if using asp.net)

```
Response.Write("id=" + somid);
```

now you can access the id from your flash app.

cheers